# Tweets insertion into mongodb via nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Here is the code using nodejs which fetches data from twitter. Now i want to store it in mongodb. Can anyone please guide me the steps how to do. Unable to do.

```
var app = require('express').createServer(),
    twitter = require('ntwitter');

app.listen(3000);

var a = 'love';
var b = 'hate';

var watchList = [a, b];
var twit = new twitter({
    consumer_key: 'FtRTll97RNnYksFDMGMyCkMwF',
    consumer_secret: 'laazWFm8p9nV6rx2H3PohRqwaB1jK1mUBus8BjEZfJlMW9gXwK',
    access_token_key: '194952208-QMGEHqeY03XUSVLHa0pPueVVMLRICVtMCLSsu6m9',
    access_token_secret: 'KivtwgKZ45rSdkEExVsYG8Ows9kPoRKl692PomUFSZ3Mp'
});

twit.stream('statuses/filter', {
    track: watchList
}, function (stream) {
    stream.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.user.screen_name + ': ' + data.text);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following snippet to insert in tweets document.

```
 stream.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("\n\n\n\n");
    db.tweets.findAndModify({
        query: {'id': 'data.id'},
        update: { $set: data},
        upsert: true,
        new: true
    })
});
```

In above code if tweet id already present it will be update otherwise insert new record.

**upsert : If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which does not insert a new document when no match is found.**

Thanks

Comment: It was of great help. I was struggling since three days. You saved me. Thanks a lot. It worked for me. 
Another question, if you can help us it would be of great assistance. Now all the data is stored in DB, now how can i get the tweets based on location and age of the person? Looking forward for your reply.

Comment: To get tweets based on location we need to incorporate below query - 
twit.stream('statuses/filter', {'locations':'-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8,-74,40,-73,41'}, function(stream) { });

Comment: Hey i'm able to store data into mongodb. Now i want to fetch data from mongodb collection and display it on browser. Can you please help me out.