# how to store stream data from twitter using mongodb and node.js tweets show in localhost store in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want connect this code to my mongodb. How do I have to connect?

outuild an effective Twitter stream client on top of NodeJS, using Socket.io and Twitter Bootstrap with few node.js lines of code. That’s the way I track node.js news!

```
twit.stream('user',{track:myList}, function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function (tweet) {
    socket.emit('message', JSON.stringify(tweet));
      console.log(data.user.screen_name + ':' + data.text);
      console.log(data);
      console.log("\n\n\n\n");
      db.tweakdb.findAndModify({
        query:{'id':'data.id'},
        update: { $set: data},
        upsery:true,
        new:true
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tweets insertion into mongodb via nodejs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407940/tweets-insertion-into-mongodb-via-nodejs)

Comment: upsert*, check your typo first